# laravel project serve not showing welcome page

Tags: php, laravel

I have started working on laravel CodeIgniter was a piece of cake in terms of development but laravel is pretty much full of stress I have installed laravel project using artisan command

```
compose create-project –-prefer-dist laravel/laravel micamp
```

After successfully installing i created an `.htaccess` file to serve laravel to web browser instead of

```
 https://localhost/micamp/public
```

to

```
 https://localhost/micamp
```

`.htaccess` which I created

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Placed the `.htaccess` on the main root directly nwo when I serve laravel project by typing in to the browser localhost/micampp

I see 404 not found instead of laravel welcome page

Comment: No need to edit ```.htaccess``` file. Run ```php artisan serve``` and access ```http://localhost:8000```

Comment: when i try to do php artisan serve it shows me 127.0.0.1 and at end of command like press Ctrl +C to stop server

Comment: I need to access main page as https://localhost/micamp

Comment: refer to https://github.com/lucabecchetti/laravel_subdir

Comment: what version laravel you are using now?

Comment: latest one i beleive it is 8

Comment: fine ... while you running this url  https://localhost/micamp/public   have you got welcome page?

Comment: it worked for me now but when i type in index.php it is showing me welcome page is it possible to serve without index.php

Comment: @NasreenS I am getting 404 not found page but when i type in index.php i got 404 not found page

Comment: yes, It is possible to remove index.php as well as public . Let me post the code below

Comment: @MarkAlan i have posted the tested answer below please check and let me know whether it is working or not

Comment: anyone to hepl me out I am unable to fix this issue yet

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove public follow the below steps ,

1. rename server.php (micamp/server.php) to  index.php
2. paste below code in .htaccess file (micamp/.htaccess)

   Options -MultiViews -Indexes

   ```
        RewriteEngine On

        # Handle Authorization Header
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
        RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

        # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
        RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 
    RewriteRule ^(css|js|images|trainer-cv)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
   ```
3. 

```
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:cache
```

then try now it will work

Comment: i think my laravel project is not properly created in main root directly i don't see any file named server.php surprisingly as i created the given htaccess and got internal server error

Comment: @MarkAlan ypu can create project using below command composer create-project laravel/laravel your_project_name . If you want particular version you can use below command composer create-project laravel/laravel your_project_name  8.0.*

Comment: ok let me delete al and create new one

Comment: I have created new project but on main root directly i still dont see such file named server.php

Comment: what version u have installed?

Comment: $uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';

Comment: if you dont have server.php leave it ...create index.php and paste above code in index.php

Comment: May GOD Help me still after creating index.pph and pasting the code in htaccess i am getting internal server error

Comment: i just realised your htaccess code is not complete one can you check it out